# svn: manual override of merge snafu

Tags: svn, merge, overwrite

I have a single messed up file in my build tree, let's call it `foo.cpp`

In my branch, I added some important features into `foo.cpp`, among other things

One of our developers merged my branch back into the trunk last week. Except he somehow got the merge for `foo.cpp` messed up, and none of the changes in that file occurred. (I guess there was a conflict of some sort, and he chose the contents of the file from the trunk rather than including the content from my branch.)

Furthermore, now when I try to merge my branch's copy of `foo.cpp` into the trunk, it says, "OK, merged!" and is content to leave foo.cpp the way it is -- presumably because it knows that a merge has *already* occurred, so now there's nothing left to do.

So:

What's the best way for me to "merge" `branches/mybranch/foo.cpp@3579` into `trunk/foo.cpp`, where "merge" in this case means "clobber" or "overwrite" so that the history of trunk/foo.cpp will show it as a descendant of `branches/mybranch/foo.cpp@3579`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

From a trunk working copy, I ran

```
svn merge --ignore-ancestry --accept theirs-full 
   http://myserver/mypath/branches/mybranch/foo.cpp@3579 foo.cpp
```

This doesn't seem to have a TortoiseSVN equivalent.